# Does the use a simple-template-id in a nested-name-specifier unambiguously mean a class template specialization?

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer, name-lookup

```cpp
struct A{
    template<typename U>
    void T(){}
};
struct B{
    template<typename U>
    struct T{
       using type = U;
    };
};
struct C:A,B{

};
int main(){
    C::T<int>::type d;
}
```

This [example](https://godbolt.org/z/1YaEo6) is accepted by neither GCC nor Clang.

As per [basic.lookup.qual#1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/basic.lookup.qual#1)

> The name of a class or namespace member or enumerator can be referred to after the​::​ scope resolution operator ([expr.prim.id.qual]) applied to a nested-name-specifier that denotes its class, namespace, or enumeration. If a​::​ scope resolution operator in a nested-name-specifier is not preceded by a decltype-specifier, lookup of the name preceding that ​::​ **considers only namespaces, types, and templates whose specializations are types**.

That means that when looking up the declarations for the template name `T`, the specialization of `T` shall denote a type in this context. On the other hand, as per [class.member.lookup#4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/class.member.lookup#4)

> If C contains a declaration of the name f, the declaration set contains every declaration of f declared in C that **satisfies the requirements of the language construct in which the lookup occurs**.

Again, when looking up the template `T` in the scope of `C`, only those templates whose specialization is a type should be considered by this lookup.  The scope of `C` does not have any declarations for `T`, hence the lookup will be performed for `S(T,C)` in every one of its base classes. The template `T` in `A` does not satisfy the requirement. Meanwhile, the template `T` declared in the scope of `B` does satisfy the requirement. So the lookup is not ambiguous and the `B::T` is the unique result. That means `C::T<int>::type d` should be well-formed. Why do both GCC and Clang reject this example? Can it be considered a bug of in both? If I missed something, what's the reason that this example should be ill-formed?

Comment: *"The template T in A does not satisfy the requirement."* Which is the *requirements* for you. `T<int>` or `T<int>::type` or  something else... I would have said the first one, but I'm not even sure it is the requirement in concern here, and it doesn't talk about *context*.

Comment: @Jarod42 I don't know what you are saying.

Comment: Adding typename/template only *"helps"* gcc [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/WTdqsM).

Comment: I don't know the answer. I meant that it is not clear what *"requirement"* means. You seems to understand that it produces valid "interpretation" for code, but `C::T<int>` is ambiguous, `C::T<int>::type` is only valid for `B`, `C::T<int>::type d{1, 42};` would be invalid for both. Adding `typename` should force the "context" to exclude `A::T`, but doesn't for clang/msvc.

Comment: From the "note" of class.member.lookup#4, we are in a place where we can have both a type or a function, so both `A::T` and `B::T` are "valid". But basic.lookup.qual#1 should indeed discards `A::T<int>` from my understanding.

Comment: @Jarod42 I think `template` is not necessary because of https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/temp.names#2.sentence-3

Comment: @LanguageLawyer: My point was mostly on `typename`. `template` doesn't hurt. (I tried with and without and no difference indeed).

Comment: @Jarod42 Why not do you think that `C::T<int>::` is a **nested-name-specifier**? The name followed by operator `::` should obey  `basic.lookup.qual#1` that is the requirement here for lookup

Comment: @Jarod42 As per [temp.res#3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/temp.res#3). I think adding `typename/template` is essentially equavelent to without the   `typename/template`

Comment: I would expect that adding `typename` (or use `using D = C::T<int>::type`) would discard non-type `A::T` (from class.member.lookup#4), but it seems not.

Comment: Not a language lawyer. As I (mis?)understand basic.lookup.qual#1, in `SomeStuff::`, `SomeStuff` should only consider class/namespace, so discard function `A::T<int>`. (but compilers disagree).

Comment: @Jarod42 If you change the example,  that is, change the template function and class in A and B to  a common function and class, respectively. Then these compilers will agree basic.lookup.qual#1. It makes no sense that they don't agree with that rule in the case of template specialization.

Comment: Worth to note, that gcc accepts `typename C::T<int>::type d;` but both 'typename` and `template` should be redundant here according to the standard.

Comment: Long ago, Johannes Schaub observed, that gcc rejects function name look-ups in a typename-specifier lookup: https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=8263 That would explain gcc's special behavior here. A very similar (but unfortunately quite mixed up issues) question was stated here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18311496/should-the-name-of-a-function-template-be-visible-during-lookup-of-a-name-preced

Comment: An [example](https://godbolt.org/z/Thqfae) that is the case fixed by P1787.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The **lookahead** required to have the lookup for `T` depend on the `::` even as the interpretation of `<` depends on the meaning of `T` is considered undesirable.  As such, lookup for a name followed by `<` is not restricted to types and namespaces regardless of any `>::` found later.  [P1787R6](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2020/p1787r6.html) fixed this, restricting the special lookup to identifiers **immediately** followed by `::` (since other kinds of names can’t refer to types or namespaces anyway).

Comment: Do you refer to [basic.lookup.qual#general-1](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.lookup.qual#general-1)? "If a name, template-id, or decltype-specifier is followed by a ​::​, it shall designate a namespace, class, enumeration, or dependent type, and the ​::​ is never interpreted as a complete nested-name-specifier." However, it requires us firstly to determine whether `T<int>` is a template-id or not. Hence temp.names#3.2 applies here to try to lookup whether `T` is a template. That means there's no other restriction for this lookup,

Comment: We would find both `A::T` and `B::T` in the scope of `C`, which is an ambiguous merge. So, Do you mean we should add the keyword `template` before `T` to make `T<int>` be considered as a template-id, after doing it, then [temp.res#general-4.1] will apply to `T`, Right?

Comment: @jackX: `template` would make /4.1 *unnecessary*, but being in a type-only context doesn’t affect what name lookup finds for `T`, so the ambiguity still renders the program ill-formed.

Comment: Doesn't [basic.lookup#general-4](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.lookup#general-4) not apply here for the name `T`? which means `T` should be a template whose specialization is a type.

Comment: @jackX: Type-only lookups are different from type-only contexts, which are a template-specific thing.  (That’s why both are italicized when introduced.)

Comment: So, According to "A qualified-id whose terminal name is dependent and that is in a type-only context is considered to denote a type. ". The name should satisfy two conditions(one is it's a dependent name, the other is it's in a type-only context), then it will affect the lookup rule, Right? In this example, although `T` is said to be in a **type-only context** but it is not a dependent name, hence, it does not affect the lookup rule, Right?

Comment: @jackX: No, not even that affects lookup—that’s the case where `typename` need *not* be used to force interpretation of a qualified name as a type **before** it can be looked up.  You can still find a non-type during instantiation; it’s just an error if you do ([temp.res.general]/3).

Comment: Is it the reason that sentence [temp.res#general-5] merely says the qualified-id is considered to denote a type when it satisfies these rules. It does not talk about **lookup** at all.  it's the difference with [basic.lookup.qual#general-1], that is **Lookup** of an identifier followed by a ​::​ scope resolution operator **considers only namespaces, types, and templates whose specializations are types**.  [This example](https://godbolt.org/z/WG8b6G) indeed proves what's the rule says.

Comment: @jackX good example! I think the core question is: Is basic.lookup.qual#general-1 strong enough to prevent the compiler from considering all matching candidates for the current 'local' template instantiation context even if the 'real' usage of the template is ill-formed for all possible cases (merge ambiguity), not just for qualified look-up scenarios. At least, one can interprete basic.lookup.qual#general-1 here as a fallback since 'considering' needn't to be more prioritised than instantiation a priori, solely ensuring the prevention of further wrong parser lines.

Comment: @Secundi  I think P1787 fixed this question by rewording the rule as "Lookup of an identifier followed by a ​::​ scope resolution operator...". That means a `template-id` is not the case stated here(i.e, there's no restriction to the `template-name` of a `tempalte-id` followed by `::` when performing the lookup).

Comment: @jackX yes, that's it.

Comment: @Secundi As Divas said in his answers, I conflated the `only-type lookup` with the `only-type context`. There's no connection between them.

Comment: An [example](https://godbolt.org/z/Thqfae) that is the case fixed by P1787.